# Some recipients see lines of code in e-mail template

Tags: email, email-template, visualforce-template

I coded an e-mail template in Visualforce, however, some recipients see lines of code in the the e-mail that's sent to them. Please see example below:

---

Hello ,

Products to be include in the quotation are the following:

Product Code:  if(!window.sfdcPage){window.sfdcPage = new ApexDetailPage();} UserContext.initialize({"networkId":"","locale":"en_US","labelLastModified":"1384456088000","isDefaultNetwork":true,"today":"11/27/2013 8:17 PM","timeFormat":"h:mm a","userPreferences":[{"index":112,"name":"HideInlineEditSplash","value":true},{"index":114,"name":"OverrideTaskSendNotification","value":true},{"index":115,"name":"DefaultTaskSendNotification","value":true},{"index":119,"name":"HideUserLayoutStdFieldInfo","value":false},{"index":116,"name":"HideRPPWarning","value":true},{"index":87,"name":"HideInlineSchedulingSplash","value":true},{"index":88,"name":"HideCRUCNotification","value":false},{"index":89,"name":"HideNewPLESplash","value":false},{"index":90,"name":"HideNewPLEWarnIE6","value":false},{"index":122,"name":"HideOverrideSharingMessage","value":false},{"index":91,"name":"HideProfileILEWarn","value":false},{"index":93,"name":"HideProfileElvVideo","value":false},{"index":97,"name":"ShowPicklistEditSplash","value":true},{"index":92,"name":"HideDataCategorySplash","value":false},{"index":128,"name":"ShowDealView","value":false},{"index":129,"name":"HideDealViewGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":132,"name":"HideKnowledgeFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},{"index":104,"name":"DefaultOffEntityPermsMsg","value":false},{"index":135,"name":"HideNewCsnSplash","value":true},{"index":101,"name":"HideBrowserWarning","value":false},{"index":139,"name":"HideDashboardBuilderGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":140,"name":"HideSchedulingGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":180,"name":"HideReportBuilderGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":183,"name":"HideAssociationQueueCallout","value":true},{"index":194,"name":"HideQTEBanner","value":false},{"index":193,"name":"HideChatterOnboardingSplash","value":true},{"index":195,"name":"HideSecondChatterOnboardingSplash","value":true},{"index":270,"name":"HideIDEGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":282,"name":"HideQueryToolGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":196,"name":"HideCSIGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":271,"name":"HideFewmetGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":272,"name":"HideEditorGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":205,"name":"HideApexTestGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":206,"name":"HideSetupProfileHeaderTour","value":true},{"index":207,"name":"HideSetupProfileObjectsAndTabsTour","value":false},{"index":213,"name":"DefaultOffArticleTypeEntityPermMsg","value":false},{"index":214,"name":"HideSelfInfluenceGetStarted","value":true},{"index":215,"name":"HideOtherInfluenceGetStarted","value":true},{"index":216,"name":"HideFeedToggleGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":268,"name":"ShowChatterTab178GuidedTour","value":false},{"index":275,"name":"HidePeopleTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},{"index":276,"name":"HideGroupTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},{"index":222,"name":"TouchExternalLinkReminderSuppression","value":false},{"index":224,"name":"HideUnifiedSearchGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":226,"name":"ShowDevContextMenu","value":true},{"index":227,"name":"HideWhatRecommenderForActivityQueues","value":false},{"index":228,"name":"HideLiveAgentFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},{"index":232,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsgOnMemberWidget","value":false},{"index":233,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsg","value":true},{"index":234,"name":"HideWhatAreGuestsMsg","value":false},{"index":235,"name":"HideNowAllowGuestsMsg","value":true},{"index":236,"name":"HideSocialAccountsAndContactsGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":237,"name":"HideAnalyticsHomeGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":238,"name":"ShowQuickCreateGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":245,"name":"HideFilePageGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":250,"name":"HideForecastingGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":242,"name":"TouchHideOptoutHover","value":false},{"index":251,"name":"HideBucketFieldGuide","value":false},{"index":263,"name":"HideSmartSearchCallOut","value":true},{"index":265,"name":"HideSocialProfilesKloutSplashScreen","value":false},{"index":273,"name":"ShowForecastingQuotaAttainment","value":false},{"index":280,"name":"HideForecastingQuotaColumn","value":false},{"index":301,"name":"HideManyWhoGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":284,"name":"HideExternalSharingModelGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":298,"name":"HideFileSyncBannerMsg","value":false},{"index":299,"name":"HideTestConsoleGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":300,"name":"HideNetworkSetupOverlayGettingStarted","value":false},{"index":302,"name":"HideManyWhoInlineEditTip","value":false},{"index":303,"name":"HideSetupV2WelcomeMessage","value":false},{"index":312,"name":"ForecastingShowQuantity","value":false},{"index":313,"name":"HideDataImporterIntroMsg","value":false},{"index":314,"name":"HideEnvironmentHubLightbox","value":false},{"index":316,"name":"HideSetupV2GuidedTour","value":true},{"index":317,"name":"HideFileSyncMobileDownloadDialog","value":false},{"index":318,"name":"HideHelpBannerQuickActionList","value":false},{"index":321,"name":"HideCustomEntityQuickActionCallout","value":true},{"index":322,"name":"HideEnhancedProfileHelpBubble","value":true},{"index":328,"name":"ForecastingHideZeroRows","value":false},{"index":330,"name":"HideEmbeddedComponentsFeatureCallout","value":false},{"index":340,"name":"HideS1BrowserUI","value":false}],"orgPreferences":[{"index":257,"name":"TabOrganizer","value":true}],"startOfWeek":"1","isAccessibleMode":false,"ampm":["AM","PM"],"renderMode":"RETRO","userId":"00540000000oOOR","dateTimeFormat":"M/d/yyyy h:mm a","dateFormat":"M/d/yyyy","uiSkin":"Theme3","language":"en_US","siteUrlPrefix":""});

---

It seems that their mail server or mail client adds the above extra code or does not understand it. Is there anything I can do on the Salesforce side to prevent this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Edit: E-mail Template Code

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Haivision Maintenance Contract has expired - {!relatedto.End_User__r.Name}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Entitlement">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

<p></p>

Dear {!relatedto.Enduser_Support_Contact__r.Name},<br></br><br></br>

Our records indicate that {!relatedto.End_User__r.Name}'s Haivision Advance Maintenance Contract has expired.<br></br><br></br>   

Effective immediately, we must disable your access to the Haivision Download Center, the Support Portal, and the Haivision Customer Engineering team.<br></br><br></br> 

It is important to renew your Haivision Advance Maintenance Contract ASAP in order to continue to receive important software updates, firmware upgrades and access to Haivision Technical Support.<br></br><br></br> 

Please contact us at 514-334-5445 ext:1 or renewals@haivision.com to renew your Haivision Maintenance Contract.<br></br><br></br>

Below is the information related to the expired contract:<br></br><br></br>
- - - -  <br></br><br></br>


<apex:repeat value="{!relatedto.Assets__r}" var="o">

<apex:OutputPanel rendered="{!o.Retired__c == false}" >
<apex:OutputPanel rendered="{!o.Returned__c == false}">
<apex:OutputPanel rendered="{!o.Asset_Status__c == 'Expired'}">


               <b>Product Code:</b>&nbsp;

                          <apex:outputField value="{!o.Name}"/><br></br>

               <b>Description:</b>&nbsp;

                          <apex:outputField value="{!o.Product2.Name}"/><br></br>

               <b>Serial Number:</b>&nbsp;  

                        <apex:OutputPanel rendered="{!o.RMAed__c == false}">

                 <apex:outputField value="{!o.SerialNumber}"/><br></br>

</apex:OutputPanel>

<apex:OutputPanel rendered="{!o.RMAed__c == true}">

                 <apex:outputField value="{!o.New_Asset_Serial_Number__c}"/><br></br>

</apex:OutputPanel>

<b>Coverage Type:</b>&nbsp;

                   <apex:outputField value="{!o.Entitlement_Level__c}"/><br></br>

<b>Coverage End Date:</b>&nbsp;

                   <apex:outputField value="{!o.Entitlement_End_Date__c}" /><br></br>

<br></br>

</apex:OutputPanel>
</apex:OutputPanel>
</apex:OutputPanel>
</apex:repeat>


<p>Thank you. </p>
<p>Haivision</p>
<p>
<a href="https://na2.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.ID}">*</a>
</p>
<p></p>
P.S. If you have already renewed your support, thank you.  <br /><br />

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: What mail client are the users viewing the message in? Are you able to get the complete email source including headers? (E.g. in gmail use the Show original)

Comment: That is definitely not coming from the recipients mail server or client. That's javascript included by Salesforce if certain components are used on a VF page. I've seen this code being created on a VF page which I red through AJAX as soon as I added an apex:outputField.  Can you share your email template code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

@Daniel Ballinger: I would not be able to get that information unfortunately. I would not be able to get the complete e-mail source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
@FrankZ It only happens to certain clients. Other clients I have view the correct content. I will add the e-mail template code to the top.

Comment: @andy Try switching the `<apex:outputField>` to a `<apex:outputText>`. That should be fine for an email template and avoid the extra javascript that gets added for an outputfield.

Comment: I've had some issues with spurious display with certain email clients (Zimbra) when my VF email template did not also include the `<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >...</messaging:plainTextEmailBody >` markup block

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced a similar issue.  apex:outputText works fine until you try to output a rich text field.  We allow our users to "insert a custom rich text paragraph" in many of our VF e-mail templates.  The extra javascript also shows up in the comment field on the task object if you save the email as an activity.  I know this doesn't answer the question but it appears I don't have the reputation to simply comment on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

As you use apex:outputField to generate the content, Salesforce adds the JavaScript code right where you use that tag the first time. I assume some customers' email filters just remove the HTML script tags but leave the actual script within the email.

Why don't you just output your fields with `<apex:outputText>` instead of with `<apex:outputField>`?

Edit inspired by @Daniel Ballinger

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling with this for the last several weeks. I couldn't find anyone that had fixed it previously so I went ahead and did it myself.

I had to write a custom component to do more work than outputText, but less overhead than outputField. Essentially it is a find and replace to make newlines into `<br />` tags and I had to pre-escape the text string and tell outputText not to escape it for me, to keep the `<br />` tags I added.

/*component*/

```
<apex:component controller="OutputTextHTML" access="global">
  <apex:attribute name="value" description="Text to be HTML formatted" type="String" assignTo="{!myText}"/>
  <apex:outputText value="{!myHTMLSafeText}" escape="false"/>
</apex:component>
```

/*controller*/

```
public class OutputTextHTML {
  public String myText{get;set;}
  public String myHTMLSafeText{
    get{
      if(myText == null)
        return myText;

      String myCleanText = myText.escapeHtml4();
      myCleanText = myCleanText.replaceAll('(\r\n)|(\n\r)|\r|\n','<br />');
      return myCleanText;
    }
  }
}
```

/*test*/

```
@isTest
public class OutputTextHTMLTest{
  public static testMethod void stringOutput(){
     OutputTextHTML htmlEncoder = new OutputTextHTML();
     //Catch null clause
     String out = htmlEncoder.myHTMLSafeText;
     htmlEncoder.myText = 'this is <a> test';
     out = htmlEncoder.myHTMLSafeText;
     System.assertEquals(out,'this is &lt;a&gt; test');

     htmlEncoder.myText = 'this\nis\na\ntest';
     out = htmlEncoder.myHTMLSafeText;
     System.assertEquals(out,'this<br />is<br />a<br />test');
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/aheber/040a5e0c2f84b68b6fdf