# Export Data to Excel File - Dump Data

Tags: visualforce, data-export, excel

I am using a VF Page that allows me to export some Record data with Related Records into Excel File Using :

```
contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#ExportFile-{!TODAY()}.xls"
cache="true"
```

Everything works fine but on the **first 2 Rows** in the generated Excel file I'm getting some Dump Data. 
 Anyone knows how to get rid of it? 
 I've check around and could not find a clear answer... 
 Thank for any help...

Example of the Dump Data:

```
if(!window.sfdcPage) { window.sfdcPage = new ApexDetailPage();}
     UserContext.initialize({"networkId":"",
                             "labelLastModified":"1436479188000",
                             "locale":"en_US",
                             "isDefaultNetwork":true,
                             "timeFormat":"h:mm a",
                             "today":"7/17/2015 1:36 PM",
  "orgPreferences":[{ "index":257, 
                       "name":"TabOrganizer",
                       "value":true},
                      { "index":113,
                        "name":"GroupTasks",
                        "value":true}],
  "userPreferences":[{ "index":112,
                       "name":"HideInlineEditSplash",
                       "value":false},  
  {"index":114,"name":"OverrideTaskSendNotification","value":false},
  {"index":115,"name":"DefaultTaskSendNotification","value":false},
  {"index":119,"name":"HideUserLayoutStdFieldInfo","value":false},
  {"index":116,"name":"HideRPPWarning","value":false},
  {"index":87,"name":"HideInlineSchedulingSplash","value":false},
  {"index":88,"name":"HideCRUCNotification","value":false}, 
  {"index":89,"name":"HideNewPLESplash","value":false},
  {"index":90,"name":"HideNewPLEWarnIE6","value":false},
  {"index":122,"name":"HideOverrideSharingMessage","value":false},
  {"index":91,"name":"HideProfileILEWarn","value":false},
  {"index":93,"name":"HideProfileElvVideo","value":false},
  {"index":97,"name":"ShowPicklistEditSplash","value":false},
  {"index":92,"name":"HideDataCategorySplash","value":false},
  {"index":128,"name":"ShowDealView","value":false},
  {"index":129,"name":"HideDealViewGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":132,"name":"HideKnowledgeFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},
  {"index":104,"name":"DefaultOffEntityPermsMsg","value":false},
  {"index":135,"name":"HideNewCsnSplash","value":false},
  {"index":101,"name":"HideBrowserWarning","value":false},
  {"index":139,"name":"HideDashboardBuilderGuidedTour","value":true},
  {"index":140,"name":"HideSchedulingGuidedTour","value":false}, 
  {"index":180,"name":"HideReportBuilderGuidedTour","value":true}, 
  {"index":183,"name":"HideAssociationQueueCallout","value":false},
  {"index":194,"name":"HideQTEBanner","value":false},
  {"index":193,"name":"HideChatterOnboardingSplash","value":false},
  {"index":195,"name":"HideSecondChatterOnboardingSplash","value":false},
  {"index":270,"name":"HideIDEGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":282,"name":"HideQueryToolGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":196,"name":"HideCSIGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":271,"name":"HideFewmetGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":272,"name":"HideEditorGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":205,"name":"HideApexTestGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":206,"name":"HideSetupProfileHeaderTour","value":false}, 
  {"index":207,"name":"HideSetupProfileObjectsAndTabsTour","value":false},
  {"index":213,"name":"DefaultOffArticleTypeEntityPermMsg","value":false},
  {"index":214,"name":"HideSelfInfluenceGetStarted","value":true},
  {"index":215,"name":"HideOtherInfluenceGetStarted","value":false},
  {"index":216,"name":"HideFeedToggleGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":268,"name":"ShowChatterTab178GuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":275,"name":"HidePeopleTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},
  {"index":276,"name":"HideGroupTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},
  {"index":224,"name":"HideUnifiedSearchGuidedTour","value":true},
  {"index":226,"name":"ShowDevContextMenu","value":true},
  {"index":227,"name":"HideWhatRecommenderForActivityQueues","value":false},
  {"index":228,"name":"HideLiveAgentFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},
  {"index":232,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsgOnMemberWidget","value":false},
  {"index":233,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsg","value":false},
  {"index":234,"name":"HideWhatAreGuestsMsg","value":false},
  {"index":235,"name":"HideNowAllowGuestsMsg","value":false},
  {"index":236,"name":"HideSocialAccountsAndContactsGuidedTour","value":true},
  {"index":237,"name":"HideAnalyticsHomeGuidedTour","value":true},
  {"index":238,"name":"ShowQuickCreateGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":245,"name":"HideFilePageGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":250,"name":"HideForecastingGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":251,"name":"HideBucketFieldGuide","value":false},
  {"index":263,"name":"HideSmartSearchCallOut","value":true},
  {"index":265,"name":"HideSocialProfilesKloutSplashScreen","value":false},
  {"index":273,"name":"ShowForecastingQuotaAttainment","value":false},
  {"index":280,"name":"HideForecastingQuotaColumn","value":false},
  {"index":301,"name":"HideManyWhoGuidedTour","value":true},
  {"index":284,"name":"HideExternalSharingModelGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":298,"name":"HideFileSyncBannerMsg","value":false},
  {"index":299,"name":"HideTestConsoleGuidedTour","value":false},
  {"index":302,"name":"HideManyWhoInlineEditTip","value":false},
  {"index":303,"name":"HideSetupV2WelcomeMessage","value":false},
  {"index":312,"name":"ForecastingShowQuantity","value":false},
  {"index":313,"name":"HideDataImporterIntroMsg","value":false},
  {"index":314,"name":"HideEnvironmentHubLightbox","value":false},
  {"index":316,"name":"HideSetupV2GuidedTour","value":true},
  {"index":317,"name":"HideFileSyncMobileDownloadDialog","value":false},
  {"index":322,"name":"HideEnhancedProfileHelpBubble","value":true},
  {"index":328,"name":"ForecastingHideZeroRows","value":false},
  {"index":330,"name":"HideEmbeddedComponentsFeatureCallout","value":true},
  {"index":341,"name":"HideDedupeMatchResultCallout","value":false},
  {"index":340,"name":"HideS1BrowserUI","value":false},
  {"index":346,"name":"HideS1Banner","value":true},
  {"index":358,"name":"HideEmailVerificationAlert","value":false},
  {"index":354,"name":"HideLearningPathModal","value":false},
  {"index":359,"name":"HideAtMentionsHelpBubble","value":false}],
  "startOfWeek":"1","isAccessibleMode":false,"isCurrentlySysAdminSU":false,
  "ampm":["AM","PM"],"renderMode":"RETRO",
  "userId":"00520000003HDQH",
  "dateTimeFormat":"M/d/yyyy h:mm a",
  "isS1Desktop":false,
  "userName":"myUser@mydomain.com",
  "dateFormat":"M/d/yyyy",
  "uiSkin":"Theme3",
  "language":"en_US",
  "siteUrlPrefix":""});
```

Comment: Admin Developer mode is turn OFF - So this is not the case here..

Comment: Really need to see more of your visualforce. If your visualforce contains apex:outputField you might need to change to use apex:outputText. Here's a similar stackexchange post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21420/some-recipients-see-lines-of-code-in-e-mail-template